# New Google Sign In Button renders initially, but if the page is refreshed it disappears. How can I go about fixing this in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, google-cloud-platform, google-signin

BELOW IS TWO OPTION SIGN IN. AN INITIAL METHOD AND AN ALTERNATE GOOGLE SIGN IN METHOD.

[`

```
      <div data-appui-vmsg data-field="email"
          data-required="Email address is required"
          data-email="Email address is not valid">

      <input name="email" ng-model="user.userEmail"  type="text" 
            placeholder="Email Id" autocomplete="off"
            required />
    </div>
    <div class="col span_12">
      <div data-appui-vmsg data-field="password"
          data-required="Password is required"></div>
      <input name="password" ng-model="user.password" type="password"
            placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off" value=""
            required />
    </div>
    <div class="col pad-t">
      <button class="primary btn" ng-click="signIn()" ng-disabled="!SForm.$valid || busy">
        <i class="fa fa-unlock"></i> LOGIN
      </button>
      <span class="forgot_pass"><a ng-click="toggleForm()" >Forgot password ?</a></span>

    </div>

    <div id="g_id_onload"
         data-client_id="XXXXXXXXXX"
         data-context="signin"
         data-ux_mode="popup"
         data-callback="handleCredentialResponse"
         data-auto_prompt="false">
    </div>

    <div class="g_id_signin"
         data-type="standard"
         data-shape="rectangular"
         data-theme="filled_blue"
         data-text="signin_with"
         data-size="large"
         data-logo_alignment="left">
    </div>

  </form>
```

I have double checked the documentation page, changed the proper library being used to <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>